# How to split arrays into unordered list include an attribute and capitalize text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, string

I tried to create a filter menu using an existing string.I'm having a simple issue I can't seem to fix. Below is a simplified version:

HTML:

```
<ul class="filter-nav"></ul>
```

JS Idea:

```
var $ = jQuery;
var data  = 'phoenix1,phoenix2,phoenix3,phoenix4,phoenix5';
data  = data .split(',');
data .forEach(function (i) { 
    $('.filter-nav').append($('<li class="filter-item"><a href="#">'+i+'').attr('data-uk-filter',i));
});
```

Unfortunately, the code does not work as expected (without text '+i+'):

Result:

```
<ul class="filter-nav">
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix1"><a href="#"></a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix2"><a href="#"></a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix3"><a href="#"></a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix4"><a href="#"></a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix5"><a href="#"></a><li>
</ul>
```

The basic issue I'm running into is splitting the array to text and attribute "data-filter" or something similar. jQuery is acceptable and I've tried some basic methods with regex and slice, but nothing seems to return what I'm looking for.

Ultimately my desired output would be an unordered list of the array include: data-filter and the capitalize text "i", like so:

```
<ul class="filter-nav">
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix1"><a href="#">Phoenix1</a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix2"><a href="#">Phoenix2</a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix3"><a href="#">Phoenix3</a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix4"><a href="#">Phoenix4</a><li>
    <li class="filter-item" data-filter="phoenix5"><a href="#">Phoenix5</a><li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Wouldn’t your desired output have `</li>` at the end instead of another `<li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are missing the closing `</li>` and `</a>`

It should be:

```
$('.filter-nav').append($( '<li class="filter-item"><a href="#">'+i+'</a></li>' ).attr('data-uk-filter',i));
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var data  = 'phoenix1,phoenix2,phoenix3,phoenix4,phoenix5';
 data  = data .split(',');
 data .forEach(function (i) { 
  $('.filter-nav').append($( '<li class="filter-item"><a href="#">'+i+'</a></li>' ).attr('data-uk-filter',i));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filter-nav"></ul>
```

Comment: `</a>` or just `</a></li>` helps as well.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I somehow forgot the closing </li> T.T

Comment: @HaDoanThanh And as Xufox mentioned, don't forget to add the closing `</a>`.